# Renaming copy of multiple files in C# in a uniform format

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-rename

I'm working with C# in ASP.net framework. I need to make a copy of files and save them.

```
File.Copy("fileFirst.txt", "fileSecond.txt"); seems to work for that.
```

However I have multiple files and I need to do this for every single file. Instead of having to type the names for every single file how can I simply have a copy of the file such that it has the original filename with a -new appended on it's back.

```
Original file:      fileFirst.txt
Copy of the file:   fileFirst-new.txt
```

NOTE: It has to to do this for as many files as I have and not just one.

Comment: you mean iterate through a loop and rename every filename in a list?

Comment: Have a look a the [Path class methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods) - you can separate out the path, file name & extension.

Comment: @TiagoSilva it doesn't have to be a list. I simply want to be able to rename my original file in a uniform format i.e orinialfilename-new.extension. When I say multiple files, I just mean, the user may need to call this function several times so every time he/she tries to make a copy,  there needs to be a way where the copy of the file takes the above mentioned format of name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code lists all the files in a directory and copies them to the same folder but with a different name.

```
    private static void RenameDirectoryFiles()
    {
        string pathfile = @"M:\_downloads\";

        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(pathfile);

        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
            try
            {
                string dire = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                string exte = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

                File.Copy($"{filePath}", $"{pathfile}\\{name}-New{exte}");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error File Copy");
            }
        }
    }
```